# java-cloudant API, I am facing problems on how to query my cloudant data using the cloudant java api

Tags: java, servlets, couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am using Cloudant Java API.

I have database created and stores doc with following structure :
 `{
  "_id": "XXX",
  "_rev": "XX",
  "Place_id": X
}`

I want to query this Database to find place_id > 100.

Currently I have created index and i am using findbyindex as shown below:

  `String Selector="{\"Place_id\": {\"$gt\": 100}}";
   List<places> p1 = db_use.findByIndex(Selector,places.class);`
 
Note: db_use is the database, using which I have inserted the records, and also checked them via the _all_docs view.

I am getting the below error:

```
    org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: Bad Request{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}   
    at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient$3.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:139)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.findByIndex(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.findByIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
at [internal classes]
```

I have followed the api reference from https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant but still with the given small examples to call functions did not solved my problems.
it will be of great help if someone can suggest my mistake or tell me the way to query my database using the java library. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "selector" at beginning of the String object:

```
String Selector="\"selector\": {\"Place_id\": {\"$gt\": 100}}";
```

Comment: thanks. it works with the selector, but you will see on their official API guide they have not used selector in the string.